# Заменить определенные значения li на новый элемент li, с помощью replaceWidth

Tags: javascript, dom

Мое решение

```html
<ul id="ul">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

```js
let newLi = document.createElement('li');
newLi.innerHTML = 'test';
for (let li of ul.querySelectorAll('li')) {
    if (li.textContent == "1") {
        li.replaceWith(newLi);
    }
}
```

Но в результате получается, что заменяется только последний li, а первые два куда-то пропадают

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш новый элемент постоянно перемещается со старого места на новое при замене на него, а на его месте ничего не остаётся. Вам нужно создавать для каждой замены новый элемент.

```js
for (let li of ul.querySelectorAll('li')) {
    if (li.textContent == "1") {
        let newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.innerHTML = 'test';
        li.replaceWith(newLi);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
```